# Sqlite and FTS tables with ICU tokenizer bug or not?

Tags: sqlite, icu, full-text-search

I have a strange problem with an FTS table in my sqlite database. I am creating a table like this:

```
CREATE VIRTUAL TABLE table01 USING fts4(name, content, tokenize=icu ru_RU);
```

Then inserting two rows, one with name and content and one only with name.

```
INSERT INTO table01(name, content) VALUES('Abc1', 'asdasd');
INSERT INTO table01(name) VALUES('Abc2');
```

And when I am trying to update or delete row with only name column filled I am getting an error "Access violation at address 7244CF96 in module 'sqlite3.dll'. Read of address 00000000.". There is all ok with other row, I can update it or delete as usual. It doesn't matter what locale do I use, I've tried en_US and many others. And there is no difference between fts3 and fts4. It seems like ICU bug, because there is no problem with built-in tokenizers of sqlite. Is it ICU or sqlite bug, or I am doing something wrong? I've tried this on SQLite Expert and in my project with all required compile options and all libraries included.

---

Latest in the stack frame:

```
msvcr100d.dll!strlen(unsigned char * buf)  Line 81  Asm
my_prog.exe!icuOpen(sqlite3_tokenizer * pTokenizer, const char * zInput, int nInput, sqlite3_tokenizer_cursor * * ppCursor)  Line 60276 + 0x9 bytes
my_prog.exe!fts3PendingTermsAdd(Fts3Table * p, const char * zText, int iCol, unsigned int * pnWord)  Line 52616 + 0x18 bytes    C
my_prog.exe!fts3DeleteTerms(int * pRC, Fts3Table * p, Mem * * apVal, unsigned int * aSz)  Line 52828 + 0x1a bytes   C
```

fts3DeleteTerms is getting null pointer instead of string and passing it down. I cannot debug it step-by-step right now (I am using amalgamation and VS 2010 cannot debug more than 65535 lines code).

Answer (score 0):

Address 00000000 is, of course, a null pointer. Sounds like an sqlite3 bug (at least in the fts4/icu glue) if it is trying to pass null to the ICU tokenizer. Can you build everything in debug mode and find out who is getting the access violation?

Comment: I have updated the main post. So there is some problem with a null pointer that is going to strlen, but unfortunately I can't find out what is the problem, because I can't debug it.

Comment: @Anonymous file a bug with sqlite3 - they shouldn't be passing NULL to strlen.